# Mysql/Php - Best way to implement DateTime into database for grouped queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I setup a database table recently and added a DataTime column which is beig saved as such :

```
id  date value

1  2017-01-01 00:00:00     584
...
5  2017-01-01 05:00:00     435
...
22 2017-01-02 02:00:00     478
```

I'm saving a value for each day (hours 0-23) , however i am now having a lot of issues querying and grouping this current format.

What i am trying to do is group the table by date (Y-m-d) , find the minimum value for each and return the time it occurred e.g :

```
2017-01-01 => (2:00 , 546)
2017-01-02 => (13:00 , 789)
```

I have this , which works somewhat but the time_formatted keeps returning 00:00 and i tried different things but can't figure out the issue.

Any alternative solutions or a fix to this problem would be greatly appreciated .

*** I'm using Laravel but can do raw queries as well**

```
$data = TableY::select
        (
            DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(val_date, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date_formatted'), 
            DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(val_date, "%H-%i") AS time_formatted'), 
            DB::raw('MIN(average_price) AS min_value')
        )
         ->groupBy('date_formatted')
         ->get();
```

**EDIT 1 : I tried this but also returning 00:00:00**

```
$statement = 
    '
        Select val_date , MIN(average_price) AS min_value from btc_data_hourly 
        GROUP BY Month(val_date) , Year(val_date) , Day(val_date)

    ';

        $data = DB::select(DB::raw($statement));
```

Result

```
{"val_date":"2017-01-01 00:00:00","average_price":967.93},
{"val_date":"2017-01-02 00:00:00","average_price":998.24},
{"val_date":"2017-01-03 00:00:00","average_price":1022.03}
```

Comment: DATE( val_date ), DAY( val_date ), MONTH(  val_date  ), YEAR(  val_date  ).  These are valid things.

Comment: Group By Month( val_date ), YEAR(  val_date  ) DESC -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - please see edit 1